# What happens to the X-gene?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the film Logan, they mention that there hasn't been a new mutant born in 25 years. Even Laura was grown and not born. Is there a mention of what happens to the mutant x-gene?

Was there a mention in the movie about what may have happened? I know there is a scene where Logan and Xavier speculate on the reason. There is also a scene with the Doctor who claims to be responsible.

What has happened that no more mutants are taking birth?

Comment: So, it finally happens what William Stryker was trying to do in X2.

Answer (score 14):

Genetically engineered corn used for [corn syrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corn_syrup) which is used as a sweetener in food and drinks. Discretely feed to the general population in order to remove the x-gene from said population.

> In the United States, cane sugar quotas raise the price of sugar; hence, **domestically produced corn syrup and high-fructose corn syrup are less costly alternatives that are often used in American-made processed and mass-produced foods, candies, soft drinks and fruit drinks.**
>
> Glucose syrup was the primary corn sweetener in the United States prior to the expanded use of high fructose corn syrup production. HFCS is a variant in which other enzymes are used to convert some of the glucose into fructose. The resulting syrup is sweeter and more soluble. Corn syrup is also available as a retail product.

**The Doctor, Zander Rice of Alkali Transigen, says so**, and we are shown the corn and entire infrastructure that supports it (**The Cornwood company and Auto-Trucks and the corporate farm next to the black family's land**). Rice is the son of the doctor of the Weapon X program that gave Logan his adamantium. Rice is the lead doctor on the new Weapon X program, X-23, which Laura is the 23rd test subject of.

Comment: When exactly does he say so? Must've missed that...

Comment: During the last scene...

Comment: Double checked with my wife and neither of us caught him saying this. Do you remember exactly what he said?

Comment: woah .. I missed this completely .. why the down votes though? Is this not a fact?

Comment: @CreationEdge it was a fairly long speech, about tweaking the food and water supply chains and suppressing the gene.

Comment: I did catch most of this, but what I found confusing was how was this supposed to have killed the gene in the whole world, and not just in the US? We know from previous movies that the xgene is not restricted to America. Does the whole world use US corn syrup?

Comment: @majaii what makes you think they restricted themselves to US production, or just corn. You can have GMO sugar cane as easily as corn.

Comment: I am not sure, but I didn't remember anything other than US production mentioned, and in your answer you talk about this US, which was what I remembered from the movie, so was just curious if I missed mention of other countries.

Comment: @majaii the US exports plenty, and the movie is set in Mexico and the US, which present day have NAFTA and open corn trade. The realism of how extensive their GMO product is marketed mirrors present day super multinational food companies like Monsanto. It may be a stretch but the movie states no more mutants in 20 years. Considering how rare mutants are anyway, and Xavier using Cerebro could find any mutant, it's not unbelievable that it's true.

Comment: @Majaii Your questions might give rise to why Canada was an "Eden" for surviving mutants, perhaps Canada doesn't use those GMOs and so mutants still exist there.